# How to run/deploy websocket in tomcat

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, websocket

I have created a websocket server using the tomcat libraries. I am using Eclipse and my websocket client is written in java using tyrus libraries.

But the way I am deploying the websocket server doesn't seem right.

Currently, I am doing Right Click>Run on Server. 
It tries to open the socket in the browser using http and gets a 404.
But the web socket gets deployed anyways in this process, and clients can connect to it.

Is there a cleaner way, by which I can deploy a websocket on Tomcat server through Eclipse?

Comment: I'm confused. You ask about a deployment problem, yet your problem seems to stem from running something. Yet at the same time there is no problem there because you state clients can connect (which also means the deployment is working). So what do you expect to happen when you "run on server" ?

Comment: The websocket connectivity works, yes. But the way I am deploying (similar to how we deploy servlets through Eclipse) doesn't seem correct. So I am looking for a standard way to deploy a websocket in tomcat using eclipse